# Asp.Net Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a weird problem ! i have ASP.NET website and i have a page with page_load which never get executedno matter what i do ,i deleted the page_load and doubled clicked the aspx page it generated page_load again i inserted my code inside and made breakpoint but it never get hit !

All other Methods gets hit normal like button click and gridview events etc.

ASP.NET 4

it only happens with this page only.

any one ever faced this weird problem ?

Comment: Do any other methods get hit? For example a button click event handler. Perhaps you're running in release mode?

Comment: yes all other methods gets hit normally , no im running debug mode!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: Is that the case of all the pages in your project or just that one?

Comment: You're not using isPostBack or anything like that?

Comment: im using ispostback but the event it self doesnt get hit !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only logical cause for you problem is that AutoEventWireup directive is set to false. Either on the page or in the web.config.

Alternatively you could use this code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLoad(e);

  //Do your stuff
}
```